# Bulk create users in Azure AD with email field

Tags: azure, csv, azure-active-directory

I am trying to "bulk create" users into my Azure Active Directory using a .csv-file. It works as expected when I follow their "UserCreateTemplate.csv"-file, but when I add a field "Email [mail]" I get an error saying "Unknown CSV header found: Email [mail]"

[image: Error when uploading .csv-file containing users]

My .csv-file looks as follows:

```
version:v1.0
Name [displayName] Required,User name [userPrincipalName] Required,Initial passwor [passwordProfile] Required,Block sign in (Yes/No) [accountEnabled] Required,First name [givenName],Last name [surname],Mail [mail]
Bulked Test User,mb1@<redacted>.onmicrosoft.com,myPassword1234,No,My,Bulk User 1,mb1@example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **doesn't support** to change the columns in [csv template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-bulk-add#understand-the-csv-template), so you couldn't add the email field.

[image]

`Email` field is only supported when **bulk inviting users**. Navigate to Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > Users > Bulk operations > Click on Bulk invite.

You can paste the email addresses under "Email address to invite [inviteeEmail] Required" column and upload the file under Bulk Invite option. This will set the email address of the invited users in the mail attribute as well.

[image]

Comment: Nice catch. I'd seen the guide, but hadn't caught the "Don't add additional columns". Will I have to use the Graph API in order to add values in other fields?

Comment: Yes, bulk creating users only supports the columns on the row 2.